# Change default login shell to /bin/bash for ALL ldap users from LDAP server - not client

Tags: bash, shell, ldap, openldap

Perhaps my google kungfu is not doing great today, but I found ways to apparently do this for each user (one by one) on the client side, or even a way to do it from the ldap side with ldapmodify *again one by one*.

What I am trying to setup is ssh based LDAP login, and its working *sorta, still need to restrict to groups, but thats another topic*, but as of now, the default shell is /bin/sh. I don't see an option in PHPLDAPADMIN for /bin/bash.

The /bin/sh is really crippling since there is no tab completion, that is the first thing I noticed and I'm sure there is more.

**How can I change the default shell for all PosixAccount's for be /bin/bash from the LDAP server so that It doesn't need to be configure on a per-user basis or per-client basis.** If not possible, how can I globally change it on the client side. I/We only manage say 50 servers, so its not impossible to add that step to LDAP integration, but for tidyness and properness, I feel it should be done from the LDAP Server.

Comment: What is your OS platform?  (OS and version; eg RedHat 6, Debian Jessie)

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenLDAP (sldap) + phpldapadmin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/phpldapadmin/templates/creation/posixAccount.xml
```

The Home Directory isn't really part of the question :P, but its the only two things I modified, and I figured I'd include it! Works great now though! But for users whom have already logged into server, it didn't retroactivly fix it, even if I changed the values in phpldapadmin, they still got the old home dir and /bin/sh.

```
<attribute id="homeDirectory">
    <display>Home directory</display>
    <!-- <onchange>=autoFill(homeDirectory;/home/%gidNumber|0-0/T%/%uid|3-%)</onchange> -->
    <order>8</order>
    <page>1</page>
</attribute>
<attribute id="loginShell">
    <display>Login shell</display>
    <order>9</order>
    <page>1</page>
    <!-- <value><![CDATA[=php.PickList(/;(&(objectClass=posixAccount));loginShell;%loginShell%;;;;loginShell)]]></value> -->
    <type>select</type>
    <value id="/bin/sh">/bin/sh</value>
    <value id="/bin/csh">/bin/csh</value>
    <value id="/bin/tsh">/bin/tsh</value>
    <value id="/bin/bash">/bin/bash</value>
</attribute>
```

Comment: Technically, this still needs to be configured on a per-user basis, but its centrally configured, which is what I meant really. I suppose I could remove the other entries, or somehow make it default, but its good enough for me to have the option available now.